# MacDown: newlines separating ordered list items following code block

Tags: markdown

I have markdown text like this

```
1. abc
1. def

        code here
    
1. ghi
1. jkl
1. mnop
```

In MacDown, it renders like this, with newlines separating the ordered list items after the code sample:

1. abc
2. def

   ```
    code here
   ```
3. ghi
4. jkl
5. mnop

How do I fix this, so the list items following the code block do not have newlines in between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not because of the code block, but because the second item is multiline. Try it without the code block and just enter random text in the second line of the second list item, the results will be the same.

There's no way to disable this behavior, as it's meant for easier distinguishment between the list items. To make it more even, leave an empty line after the first list item, so every item will be equally spaced.